# Receber 3 valores aleatórios e alocar em 3 variáveis do menor para o maior

Tags: java

Preciso escrever um programa que receba 3 valores aleatórios e alocar os 3 valores em 3 variáveis MENOR, INTERMEDIARIO e MAIOR. Tentei algo assim, mas na hora de imprimir os valores, recebo o erro que as var A B C não foram inicializadas.

Erro:

```
variable A might not have been initialized
variable B might not have been initialized
variable C might not have been initialized
```

Código:

```
int A,B,C;
System.out.println("Digite 3 valores!");
int vala = input.nextInt();
int valb = input.nextInt();
int valc = input.nextInt();

if        (vala > valb && vala > valc)  { A = vala;}
else if (valb > vala && valb > valc)  { A = valb;}
else if (valc > vala && valc > valc)  { A = valc;}
else if (vala < valb && vala < valc)  { B = vala;}
else if (valb < vala && valb < valc)  { B = valb;}
else if (valc < vala && valc < valb)  { B = valc;}
else if (vala > valb && vala < valc || vala < valb && vala > valc)  { C = vala;}
else if (valb > vala && valb < valc || valb < vala && valb > valc)  { C = valb;}
else if (valc > vala && valc < valb || valc < vala && valc > valb)  { C = valc;}

System.out.println(A);
System.out.println(B);
System.out.println(C);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisar iniciar as variáveis locais `A`, `B` e `C` com algum valor. Provavelmente, no seu caso, com o valor zero:

```
int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0;
```

Se a variável é local e o `= 0` é omitido, então a variável não tem valor, [nem mesmo zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2843433/2387977). A atribuição automática de `int` para o valor zero só aplica-se aos campos de uma classe.

Aproveitando, começar as variáveis Java com letra maiúscula não faz parte do padrão da linguagem. Prefira começar os nomes de variáveis em letra minuscula.

Answer (score 2):

O código de erro já diz tudo

```
variable A might not have been initialized
variable B might not have been initialized
variable C might not have been initialized
```

Ou seja, você não inicializou as variáveis. Para isso:

```
int a=0,b=0,c=0;
```

Você pode melhorar o código utilizando menos comparações e variáveis.
Podemos utilizar quatro variáveis, sendo elas a,b,c para os valores e uma aux para realizar as trocas de valores.

```
    int a,b,c,aux;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Digite 3 valores!");
    a = input.nextInt();
    b = input.nextInt();
    c = input.nextInt();
```

A primeira etapa é encontrar o maior valor entre os três números.

```
    if (a > b) { // a é maior que b? trocamos seus valores.
        aux = a; // variável aux recebe o valor contido em a
        a = b;   // a recebe o valor de b
        b = aux; // b recebe o valor de aux, que contém o valor inicial de a
    }
```

Repetimos a comparação para que a variável c receba o maior valor

```
    if (b > c) { // b é maior que c? trocamos seus valores
        aux = b; // variável aux recebe o valor contido em b
        b = c;   // b recebe o valor de c
        c = aux; // c recebe o valor de aux, que contém o valor inicial de b
    }
```

Com esses duas comparações nos certificamos que o valor contido em c é o maior.
Para finalizar basta ajustar os valores de a e b com a mesma comparação inicial.

```
    if (a > b) { // a é maior que b? trocamos seus valores.
        aux = a; // variável aux recebe o valor contido em a
        a = b;   // a recebe o valor de b
        b = aux; // b recebe o valor de aux, que contém o valor inicial de a
    }
```

Por último, imprima os valores.

```
    System.out.println("Menor: "+a);
    System.out.println("Intermediario: "+b);
    System.out.println("Maior: "+c);
```

Outra forma bem mais fácil e reutilizável para diversos problemas:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a,b,c;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Digite 3 valores!");
        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();
        c = input.nextInt();

        int meuArray[] = {a,b,c}; //inicializa nosso array com os valores das 3 variáveis.

        Arrays.sort(meuArray); //ordena os valores 

        System.out.println("Menor: "+meuArray[0]);
        System.out.println("Intermediario: "+meuArray[1]);
        System.out.println("Maior: "+meuArray[2]);
    }
}
```